Can not find any element in selenium in python
I use driver like this
import ...
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# then I open target URL in chrome manually
input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//textarea')

sometimes it works, but sometimes I can not locate the target element.
Then I try it in debug, after breakpoint, I can see that there is a textarea tag in driver.page_source, but
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//textarea') 

still doesn`t work, even
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html') 

will return no such element.
I try driver.refresh(), it works.
I don`t know what happen to the driver

It might be that you are evaluating your page before it fully loads. Try some sleep method hooked to the driver instance.

thank you!
but with driver.page_source I can see there is textaera tag in the string
and when debug the code, I think I wait enough time to fully load the page.
is that means the driver only load part of full page_source and cannot parse the xpath?
